# How do I set additionalProperties to false when using an array?

Tags: jsonschema

The file being validated looks like this:

```
MyArray:
  - someItemWithRandomName:
    one: f9jfw9j302
    two: 09dj0293jff
    three: 09dj0293jff
  - someOtherItemWithRandomName:
    one: f9jfw9j302
    two: 09dj0293jff
    three: 09dj0293jff
  - anotherItem:
    one: f9jfw9j302
    two: 09dj0293jff
    three: 09dj0293jff
```

I'm validating it like this:

```
"MyArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "one": {
          "type": "string"
      },
      "two": {
          "type": "string"
      },
      "three": {
          "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't want to allow fields in the array items not defined in the schema but `"additionalProperties": false` doesn't work because the array item's keys can be any string. How do you accommodate this?

### Edit

Here is a live example of my validation. The YAML I assume is going to be converted to JSON like in this example before it's validated: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/PBmLkkBl

Comment: What you have should work based on your description. Can you post an example of data that currently passes that shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a level in your schema, to allow the array item's object properties to be named anything.

Try this:

```
"MyArray": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "one": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "two": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "three": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you want to put a restriction on the names used in that intermediary level, you can replace "additionalProperties" with "patternProperties":

```
...
"patternProperties": {
  "^[0-9]$": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or if you want to use a schema for the property names, you can use "propertyNames".

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Comment: I'm confused when I wrap it in another `additionalProperties` like this it does not work at all.

Comment: I think you example is invalid? https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/nCHjYHJu

Comment: Ok I think this is your example without my missing bracket. It doesn't seem to validate correctly: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/A5N28Hnr. If I add a prop named "four" it passes validation.

Comment: I finally have a complete live example here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/TmcvpnbM

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Your first example was nested one level too deep - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/A5N28Hnr

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

My solution was to just remove the null items of the array because they were not being used. I think the only way to handle this correctly would be to do some kind of conditional validation to allow all properties with null values - if that's even possible.